# Terrain picking in mapbox-gl-js

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, picking

I'm using queryRenderedFeatures as the basis for a picking feature (like in here  https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/). This approach provides a simple way of knowing which object is under the cursor, inspect its contents and determine its position.

How this functionality can be replicated when a 3d terrain is activated? QueryTerrainFeatures will not return any info associated to the terrain. In essence I'd like to determine the lat/long of the terrain triangle where the user clicked.

Do you have any recommendations on how to implement it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.